# Exit stand-by only when power button is pressed

Tags: windows-7, standby, acpi

I was wondering if there is any setting to make my PC exit stand-by only when the power button is pressed on my computer case?

My laptop does this out of the box, it won't exit stand-by on any other hardware event. My PC however will also exit stand-by when I press a keyboard or a mouse button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for the mouse, although the check box is <strike>not there</strike> often missing for keyboards:
http://www.online-tech-tips.com/windows-7/prevent-a-mouse-from-waking-windows-7-up-from-sleep-mode/

Also look in the BIOS settings for "Wake on Keyboard".

Comment: Aha, thank you! I also found the same setting on my keyboard, and they both work.